# Speed up ST_snap query in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgis

## Explanation

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL using the PostGIS extension. Both tables are representing streets as linestrings from a province.

[image]

`streetsA` table (orange lines) has a table size of 96 MB (471026 rows), the second table `streetsB` (green lines) has a storage size of 78 MB (139708 rows). The streets differ a bit in their positions, that is why I applied a `ST_Snap` function to match streetsB to streetsA.

```
create table snapped as select ST_snap(a.geom, b.geom, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)*0.5) from streetsA as a, streetsB as b;
```

However due to the large size of the tables, the query takes more than 5 hours to complete. I haven't changed anything in the postgres settings. Is it a good idea to perform the query on such a large dataset? Does a spatial index make sense for this query? I am using a 16GB RAM Laptop with Core i7.

The `EXPLAIN` method gives me following output:

- `Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..5264516749.25 rows=65806100408 width=32)`
- `Seq Scan on streetsa a  (cost=0.00..16938.26 rows=471026 width=153)`
- `Materialize  (cost=0.00..12127.62 rows=139708 width=206)`
- `Seq Scan on streets b  (cost=0.00..11429.08 rows=139708`

Comment: what is your `work_mem` setting?

Comment: What do you get from `EXPLAIN select ST_snap(a.geom, b.geom, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)*0.5) from streetsA as a, streetsB as b`

Comment: Isn't this returning an unfiltered cartesian join with 65 billion rows?

Comment: @richyen the work_mem settings are 64 MB, regarding the `EXPLAIN` method you can find my edits in my question.

Comment: You could possibly loop over all records and snap only to those that are in in its vicinity?